# Passing initial data from django to angular 2

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm working on my first angular 2 app in an existing Django/Angular1 setup. We used to pass initial data in a django template to be consumed by angular in a  tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = '{{ id }}';
</script>
```

Then the angular app could utilize it by:

```
$scope.id = id;
```

How can I accomplish this same functionality with Angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think django has to do nothing here.
According to `angular 2`

```
this.id = id
```

Comment: That did it! Man...seems like a dumb question now...Thank you!